# Fabric: button title in TWTRLoginButton don't show (iOS Xcode 6.3.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter-fabric

I have this question. I'm using Fabric to build my app, and I'm coded this lines to create my Login Button

```
TWTRLogInButton *logInButton = [TWTRLogInButton buttonWithLogInCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
//code in here
    }];
```

but my result with this is only showing the little bird of Twitter and nothing else (without title). Anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: it's necessary verify that TwitterKitResources.bundle is added in the project. If not, you need add it from TwitterKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/